# passing char*[] from c++ dll Struct to c#  

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

I'm trying to pass the following structure through c++ DLL to c#:

```
struct name 
{   char* myArray[3];
    char firstname[100]; 
    char lastname[100]; 
}; 

void Caller(struct name * demo) 
{
  strcpy(demo->firstname,"hello");
  demo->myArray[0]="hello";
  demo->myArray[1]="hello";
  demo->myArray[2]="hello";
  ping(demo);                     //call to c# function
}
```

Below is my c# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct name
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
   public string firstname;
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
   public string lastname;

   //what should i marshal here for  char* myArray[3];
} ;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   name myname = new name();
   ping( ref myname);
}

public static void ping(int a,ref name myname)
{
   Console.WriteLine(myname.firstname+"\n");
}
```

I am able to import first and last name from c++ dll.

What should I do to import char pointer array form c++?

Comment: Have you tried public string[] myArray;

Comment: yeah tried it...
but geting error in following line
  IntPtr c= myname.myArray;

Comment: You'll need to declare it as IntPtr[] and initialize it before calling the function with new IntPtr[3].  Then convert the strings afterwards with Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  High odds for unstoppable memory leaks.

Comment: Not sure but you might declare it:
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=3)] string[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Name
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string FirstName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string LastName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public string[] Array;
};
```

for my complete solution check Foo.cpp and Program.cs: https://gist.github.com/3779066